ClosedXML Gives 'File Corrupt' Error after written by NPOI extension, But File is Not Corrupt C#
I am using the ClosedXML package (version 0.95.4) to open an Excel file (.xlsx), which was written via NPOI extension and upload to blob storage in Azure. So, the file have access.
However, when I attempt to open the file using ClosedXML, I receive an error that the file is corrupt.
System.IO.FileFormatException: 'File contains corrupted data.'
When I open the file directly using Excel, the file opens normally, with no errors. I should also add that this code was working perfectly before, and suddenly stopped working. The file has .xlsm extension.
This is the code where I write to the file -
   public Stream PopulateExcelTemplate(List<Dictionary<string, string>> dayReadingsDictionaryList, Stream stream, string filename)
    {
 var uploadExcelStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), filename), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
       var workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(stream);
       var userUploadSheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(ExcelConstants.UserUploadSheet);
       var formulaSheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(2);
       formulaSheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation = true;
       var descriptionRow = userUploadSheet.GetRow(ExcelConstants.descriptionRow);
       var DateTimeRow = userUploadSheet.GetRow(ExcelConstants.DateTimeRow);
       var rowNumber = DateTimeRow.RowNum + 1;
       foreach (var dayReadingsDictionary in dayReadingsDictionaryList)
       {
           foreach (var obj in dayReadingsDictionary)
           {
               var jsonKey = obj.Key.Replace("\"", "").Trim();
               var jsonValue = obj.Value == null || obj.Value.Trim() == "null" ? string.Empty : obj.Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < descriptionRow.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
               {
                   if (jsonKey.Equals(Constants.DateTime) &&
                DateTimeRow.Cells[columnIndex] != null &&
                DateTimeRow.Cells[columnIndex].ToString().Trim().Contains(Constants.DateTimeConstant))
                   {
                       var jsonDateTimeValue = System.DateTime.Parse(jsonValue);
                              
                   userUploadSheet.GetRow(rowNumber).GetCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue(jsonDateTimeValue);
                                    formulaSheet.GetRow(rowNumber).GetCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue(jsonDateTimeValue);
                break;
                    }
            else if (descriptionRow.Cells[columnIndex] != null && descriptionRow.Cells[columnIndex].ToString().Trim().Equals(jsonKey))
            {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonValue))
                            userUploadSheet.GetRow(rowNumber).CreateCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue(double.Parse(jsonValue));
                        else
                            userUploadSheet.GetRow(rowNumber).CreateCell(columnIndex);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            rowNumber++;
        }

And this is how I read the file -
    XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileStream);
    IXLWorksheet plantSheet = workbook.Worksheet(ExcelConstants.detailSheet);
    var uploadExcelStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),         constants.NPOIFile), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    workbook.SaveAs(uploadExcelStream);
    uploadExcelStream.Position = 0;
    var workbookNPOI = WorkbookFactory.Create(uploadExcelStream);
    uploadExcelStream.Close();

The code breaks at the first line of reading -
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileStream);
Any help would be great.

What's the full stack trace? I suspect this exception is thrown by OpenXML. ClosedXML is just a wrapper around OpenXML.

System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.OpenCore(Stream stream, Boolean readWriteMode)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheets(Stream stream)
at .ExcelFileContentExtractorService.GetADIPlantUploadedMetrics(Stream fileStream, Int32 processDetailId, ILogger logger) in \Services\ExcelFileContentExtractorService.cs:li

As you can see, the exception is thrown by System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open. So this isn't a ClosedXML issue. Either the package truly is corrupt, in which case you should log an issue with the NPOI project, or if the package isn't corrupt, you should log it with Microsoft.
